# how to change background color and/or font in xcode 5's documentation window

Tags: xcode5

I'm using Xcode 5 and I use a very dark theme for coding with a black background (usually in a dark room).  Whenever I switch to Xcode's documentation window (which is often) to look something up, zap !!!!

That flash to a bright white background is like a nuke going off, a layer gets burned off my retinas.  Anybody know if there's a way to change the background color and/or fonts for the documentation window in Xcode 5 ?